# How can print out my object properties base on my dropdown-menu?

Tags: javascript

I have a dropdown-menu with option : A, B. 
I have 2 objects : A, B.

Their property is

```
var A = { name:"Andrew", age:26, country:"United States" };
var B = { name:"Barry", age:23, country:"Italy" };
```

I want to display A information when A is selected from the drop-down menu, and vice of versa.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>JSON</title>
</head>

<body>

  <form>
    Student :
    <select id="dd" onchange="myStudent()">
      <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
    </select>

    <p>Selected Student :
      <input type="text" id="student" size="2" value="A">
    </p>
  </form>

  <div id="result">Details :
    <br>
  </div>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function myStudent() {


    var dd = document.getElementById("dd");
    var selected = dd.options[dd.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById("student").value = selected;
  }

  var A = {
    name: "Andrew",
    age: 26,
    country: "United States"
  };
  var B = {
    name: "Barry",
    age: 23,
    country: "Italy"
  };

  var result = document.getElementById("result");

  result.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(A, undefined, 6);
</script>

</html>
```

I couldn't B to display. Can someone please give me some hints ?

[Here is my JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/bxwaptpj/)

Comment: Since `A` and `B` are defined in global scope (which is window), you can do something like this:  `JSON.stringify(window[selected], undefined, 0);`

Comment: @DavinTryon : I'm trying that now. I'll let you know.

Comment: I've tried that [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/bxwaptpj/3/) - now nothing got display. :(

Answer (score 1):

You never changed the document HTML in the myStudent() call.

First, I moved the code which defined `selections`, `selections["A"]`, and `selections["B"]` before the myStudent() function so that it would not be undefined.

I moved `A` and `B` into the `selections` object to avoid some nasty `eval` when passing the selection into the `JSON.stringify` function. Otherwise, in order to pass the object into the `JSON.stringify` function I would have needed to do something like `JSON.stringify(eval(selected), undefined, 6);` which is ugly and just bad practice.

Then I put code to find which one was selected into the `myStudent` function.

I'm still not sure what the purpose of the parameters `undefined` and `6` are for in `JSON.stringify`. Hopefully someone more illuminated than me might be able to comment.

The code should work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>JSON</title>
</head>

<body>

  <form>
    Student :
    <select id="dd" onchange="myStudent()">
      <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
    </select>

    <p>Selected Student :
      <input type="text" id="student" size="2" value="A">
    </p>
  </form>

  <div id="result">Details :
    <br>
  </div>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var selections = {};
  selections["A"] = {
    name: "Andrew",
    age: 26,
    country: "United States"
  };
  selections["B"] = {
    name: "Barry",
    age: 23,
    country: "Italy"
  };

function myStudent() {

    var dd = document.getElementById("dd");
    var selected = dd.options[dd.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById("student").value = selected;
    
    var result = document.getElementById("result");
    result.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(selections[selected], undefined, 6);
  }

  var result = document.getElementById("result");
  result.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(selections["A"], undefined, 6);

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Your code is working. Thank-you for that. But I'm wonder if there a way that I can make adjustment base on what I got. Please advise.

Comment: If you're really picky about keeping what you have, you should still move `myStudent()` down beneath the declarations of `A` and `B` so that `A` and `B` are in scope. You would need to add the line `var result = document.getElementById("result");` to the bottom of the `myStudent` function to get the result div, and under it add `result.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(eval(selected), undefined, 6);` to change the HTML itself. `eval(selected)` is necessary, as it will turn the string that you got from `document.getElementById("student").value = selected;` into the actual object.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly advise. I will try that now. If it works the reward will be yours.

Comment: I did that, and I got one small problem `Uncaught ReferenceError: selected is not defined`

Comment: I got that because my selected variable is in my function, and then when I tried moving it out again, everything break so badly. NO idea what to do now..

Comment: Selected should still be in your function. The code of your function should look like this:

`var dd = document.getElementById("dd");
    var selected = dd.options[dd.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById("student").value = selected;
    
    var result = document.getElementById("result");
    result.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(eval(selected), undefined, 6);`

Comment: Okay - what happen to my function `student()` ? Can you up answer please ?

Comment: The code that I pasted in the comment two above should be the code inside the function `myStudent()`. I'm not going to answer above because the way that I have it up there is a better way of doing it and I don't want to compromise the answer in case anyone else has the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
var dd = document.getElementById("dd");
var selected = dd.options[dd.selectedIndex].text;
```

You are using a variable before it is declared.

Comment: I fixed it, but I don't think it is an answer.